# Issue with Using Series to Approximate $\int_{1}^{e^2}\frac{e^x}{x}dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

I want to use a series to estimate $\int_{1}^{e^2}\frac{e^x}{x}dx$.  When I write the series representation (a=0) in the integrand, divide by x term-by-term, integrate term-by-term, and put my answer back into a series form, I get a undefined first term (n=0 term).
On the other hand, if I truncate to the third-order Taylor polynomial (a=0) first, then divide by x, then integrate term-by-term, I have no issues.
Is there an order of operations issue here that I am not aware of?  Why can't I truncate to $T_3(x)$ last?

Comment: Hint: Let  $u = \ln(x)$, then $$\int_1^{e ^ 2} \frac{e^x}{x} \ dx = \int_0^2 e^{e^u}\ du$$ This gives you the [exponential integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ei(x))

Comment: I don't see why you would get an undefined term here. We have that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$, so the first term is simply $1$. If we divide that by $x$, then the first term is $1/x$ which we can integrate.

Answer (score 2):

So we agree that whether or not we truncate the Taylor series we have ($x > 0, \ n\geq 0$)
$$\frac{e^x}{x} \approx \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}\hspace{2.5cm} \frac{e^x}{x} = \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}$$
Then :
$$
\int_1^{e^2} \frac{e^x}{x} = \left[ \ln(x) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k}}{k!\cdot k}\right]_1^{e^2} = \overbrace{\ln(e^2)}^{=2} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{2k}}{k!\cdot k} - \left(\overbrace{\ln(1)}^{=0} +  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!\cdot k}  \right)
$$
And here I don't see where you have problem ?